# How to configure freebase java client to connect through a proxy?

Tags: java, http, proxy, freebase

I am looking for a way to configure the freebase java api to connect to [freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) through a proxy. I have set up sytem properties

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy"); 
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
System.setProperty("http.proxySet", "true");
```

but it doesn't have any effect. Could anybody help?

Comment: http.proxySet is an urban myth. It has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nop, it does not work. I do not need to do authentication. I have found another solution. I have modified the freebase client -- the source code is freely available. The freebase client uses HttpClient4 , so you need to create HttpProxy object (and set your proxy details), and provide it to HttpClient.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that an authentication is required, in this case please add

```
System.setProperty( "http.proxyUser", "user" );
System.setProperty( "http.proxyPassword", "password" );
```

or the `hostname` (proxy) isn't resolve this could be checked by `ping hostname`, you could add the IP-address instead. For further anaysis you should add the stacktrace of your exception.

`HttpURLConnection` has a method `isUsingProxy()` which could be useful for diagnostic log messages.

Further details you might find [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0085.html)

Comment: Nop, it does not work. I do not need to do authentication. I have found another solution. I have modified the freebase client -- the source code is freely available. The freebase client uses HttpClient4 , so you need to create HttpProxy, and provide it to HttpClient.